# Where to download JDBC Image Mosaic?

Tags: geoserver

Documentation [says](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaicjdbc.html) that I should:
"Download the JDBC Image Mosaic extension from the GeoServer download page."
But [download page](http://geoserver.org/download/) do not content any downloading link to JDBC Image Mosaic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the link corresponding to the version of GeoServer you are using then you will see JDBC image mosaic under coverages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't click on the link in the download page.  Go [here](http://geoserver.org/release/stable/) and under the section on Coverage formats you will find a link to the JDBC Image Mosaic and many other plugins as well.